# How I can solve a system of this type

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

How I can solve a system of this type
$$\begin{cases}
\ddot{x_{1}}(s) - x_{1}(s)  \, \dot{x_{1}}^{2}(s)  &=0\\
\ddot{x_{2}}(s) - x_{1}(s)  \, \ddot{x_{1}}(s)  +  \dot{x_{1}}^{2}(s)  &=0
\end{cases}$$
Thank you in advance

Comment: You could try introducing $x_3 = x_1'$ and $x_4 = x_2'$ and see if the resulting system of four 1st-order equations is more tractable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that first equation does not depend on $x_2$. Hence, you can solve it first, then substitute the solution to the second equation, and then solve second equation.

First equation can be solved by substitution $x_1' = p(x_1)$, where $p$ is unknown function. Then we have $x_1'' = \frac{d}{ds}p(x_1(s)) = p' p$. Therefore, you first equation reduces to
$$
p'(x_1) p(x_1)=x_1 p^2(x_1).
$$
Hence, either $p(x_1) = 0$, or $p'(x_1)=x_1 p(x_1)$. Both these equations are integrable, and you can find $p$ explicitly. Then, you integrate the equation $x'=p(x)$, and find explicitly $x_1(s)$.